# jquery append select option after option

Tags: php, jquery, append

i use  jquery  to append option to select
it's worked but i want add

```
<option value="0">choose category</option>
```

after any selected
when i add it in html it's hidden after select option apeend

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="cat"]').on('change', function() {
        $('select[name="subcat"]').removeClass('hidden');
        $('select[name="subcat2"]').addClass('hidden');
        //$('select[name="subcat2"]').find('option').remove().end(); 
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('getCat') }}/'+stateID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="subcat"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="subcat"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="subcat"]').empty();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Be more clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are calling empty function before appending. So if you have hard coded option `<option value="0">choose category</option>` it will be removed before new options are added.

```
success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="subcat"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="subcat"]').append('<option value="0">choose category</option>');
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="subcat"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simulation of your problem, see if that's what you want?

[Link jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoxgybcq/)

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cat">
  <option value="0">choose category</option>
  <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
  <option value="2">Cat 2</option>
</select>
<select name="subcat" style="display:none">
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="cat"]').on('change', function() {
        //$('select[name="subcat"]').removeClass('hidden');
        //$('select[name="subcat2"]').addClass('hidden');
        //$('select[name="subcat2"]').find('option').remove().end(); 
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID) {
            $.ajax({
                        data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            1: 'Sub cat 1',
                            2: 'Sub cat 2',
                            3: 'Sub cat 3',
                        }
                    }),
                    delay: 1
                },
                url: '/echo/json/',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="subcat"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="subcat"]').append('<option value="0">choose category</option>');
                    $.each(data.object, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="subcat"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                    $('select[name=subcat]').show();
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="subcat"]').empty();

        }
    });
});
```